# How to set 404 page response header IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I have a custom 404 page I've made (hardcoded page in html / tiny bit of php)

I'm using iis7, and am using the web.config file to redirect to my 404 page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.php" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is producing a "soft 404" - in other words the response header is giving code 200 (all ok) instead of code 404.

How do I change that to give a response header of code 404.

Do I do that on the page, or in the web.config file?

I've read a lot of posts on this and tried a lot of things without success, so any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,

Phil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

All you need to do is add a line in php to set the header:

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```